# Enumeration + char?

Tags: matlab

How to properly define a superclass for this `enumeration`:

```
classdef SubTypeEnum < ????????
    enumeration
        base      ('this_is_super_simple_string1')
        extended  ('this_is_super_simple_string2_4_6')
    end
end
```

What do I put instead of question marks? `char` and `string` are sealed. Any way around?

I'm using MATLAB 2017b.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use an enumeration? Would, for instance, a class with a bunch of constant properties suffice?

Comment: I think it would. I was just wondering if it possible in here. I think that class with a bunch of constant fields is exactly an enumeration. That is why I was looking into this. But i think you are right in a way that class would work as well. Or even structure with fields generated by a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a superclass here. Implement it like this:

```
classdef MyEnum
    properties
        mystring
    end
    methods
        function obj = MyEnum(str)
            obj.mystring = str;
        end
    end
    enumeration
        base      ('this_is_super_simple_string1')
        extended  ('this_is_super_simple_string2_4_6')
    end
end
```

and use it like this:

```
>> a = MyEnum.base
a = 
    base
>> a.mystring
ans =
    'this_is_super_simple_string1'
```